# Illegal assignment from List<SObject> to List<String>

Tags: apex, soql

I have the following code sample:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string getDunsByRecordId(id currentRecordID) {
    String q = 'SELECT DunsNumber FROM Account  where Id=:currentRecordID limit 1';
    List<String> dunsNumbers= Database.query(q);
    return dunsNumbers[0];
}
```

I want to receive the DUNS number of the record that I'm currently on, and retrieve it to the component.

The thing is, from what I understand, a query always return a list as a result, not a string.

When I write the line `List<String> dunsNumbers= Database.query(q);`, there is an error:

> Illegal assignment from List to List

1. How do i make it work? How do I receive one string as a duns number?
2. Is there a way to receive a string, and not a list, as a result of a query?

Comment: You will receive `List<Account>` from your query and then you can loop on it to get your `DunsNumber` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns list of accounts. You cannot assign it to a list of String. Whenever you need field value from any object you need SOQL. Try the below code.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string getDunsByRecordId(id currentRecordID) {
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, DunsNumber 
                              FROM Account  
                              WHERE Id = :currentRecordID 
                              LIMIT 1];
    return (!accounts.isEmpty()) ? accounts[0].DunsNumber : '';
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by custom field?

Comment: `DunsNumber` is a standard field in account so need to append __c.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
public static string getDunsByRecordId(id currentRecordID) {
    String q = 'SELECT DunsNumber FROM Account  where Id=:currentRecordID limit 1';
    List<Account> dunsNumbers= Database.query(q);
    String dunsNumber = '';
    if(dunsNumbers.size() != 0)
       dunsNumber = dunsNumbers[0].DunsNumber;
    return dunsNumber;
}
```

As you are querying only one account so no need to looping over it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this *[Using SOQL Queries That Return One Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_single_row.htm)* in Apex Developer Guide. You can get the single values from SOQL as below.

```
String name = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:currentRecordID limit 1].Name;
Double AnnualRevenue = [SELECT AnnualRevenue FROM Account WHERE Id=:currentRecordID limit 1].AnnualRevenue;

System.debug('name'+name);
System.debug('AnnualRevenue'+AnnualRevenue);
```